# Can't type letter 'v' into gdb

Tags: bash, gdb, zsh, cgdb

I'm having this weird problem where gdb won't let me type the letter 'v' into it's prompt. GDB also won't let me copy-paste the letter either. Copy-pasting a series of characters containing the letter results in the 'v' being removed. For example, copy-pasting "RecoveryTest" results in "RecoeryTest" appearing in the prompt.

Interestingly, after I quit GDB I see the two following lines:

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x928ef28
Cannot access memory at address 0x928ef20
```

I've tried starting up gdb in both zsh and bash and this problem persists with both shells.

I've also tried using cgdb and the problem exists with that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! My `~/.inputrc` file had the following lines:

```
set keymap vi-command
v: ""
```

Removing the last line fixed my problem.